# Command to exit to windows

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need a command to exit the game, i mean, exit to the desktop or windows (whatever). Because i'm doing a pause menu and wan't to do this and already have the button but don't have the exit command.
I use C# and work on Unity 5 
Thanks

Comment: Are you outputting a standalone, using the Unity plugin, or webgl?

Answer (score 1):

Simply have the button call `Application.Quit();`, after saving any data that needs to be saved.

Comment: When i put it it says that it's unknow for the application method with a "?"

Comment: I'm not familiar with the editor, is that an error, have you tried running it?

Comment: I concur that Application.Quit() works for standalone applications, however how do you close applications which are build for the UnityWebPlay? http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.Quit.html

Comment: also that SS is monodevelop.

Comment: What does "quit" mean when you're running in a web browser?